# ALTER TABLE Issue in Aurora MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora, alter-table

I was trying to execute the below SQLs in Aurora MYSQL DB v5.7.12 but getting getting error like this. I searched all over internet this is exact syntax shown everywhere, not sure what I am missing.

Failure Message is:

> (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALTER TABLE discount ADD CONSTRAINT discountpkey PRIMARY KEY (d' at line 17")

SQLs used:

```
CREATE TABLE discount
(
discount_id          varchar(50) not null,
discount_name        varchar(255),
hr_status             varchar(50),
program_status        varchar(50),
created_by            varchar(50) not null,
created_timestamp     varchar(20) not null,
updated_by            varchar(50) not null,
updated_timestamp     varchar(20) not null
);

ALTER TABLE discount ADD CONSTRAINT discountpkey PRIMARY KEY (discount_id);
```

Appreciate if anyone helps.

Comment: [This issue is not reproducible in MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oELNqcUpJBXJCGmKpAjFrU/0). May be related to some issue with Aurora.

Comment: Tried the same SQL here - https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_editor . Getting same exact error I get in my lambda function

Comment: It works in 5.7: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oELNqcUpJBXJCGmKpAjFrU/1

Comment: You can't put multiple statements in the w3schools editor.

Comment: Thanks for giving idea. Worked fine after splitting into multiple rows in a loop. Thank you for the suggestions.